# IIS Rewrite: Match only if first thing after domain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have an IIS rewrite rule written like so:

```
<rule name="Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="foo/(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="bar/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

However, I would like to modify this so it onyl matches if 'foo' is the first thing after the domain.

So for example

```
www.example.com/foo/a/b/c
```

should redirect to

```
www.example.com/bar/a/b/c
```

But

```
www.example.com/bar/a/b/foo/c/d
```

Should NOT get redirected. Currently my rule changes the above to

```
 www.example.com/bar/c/d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I just needed to add a ^ so the rule becomes:

```
<rule name="Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^foo/(.*)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="bar/{R:1}" />
 </rule>
```